# Difference form.Close() and form.hide()

Tags: vb.net

What is the difference between form.Close() and form.Hide() in desktop application.

i know Form_Close event will not be fired in form.Hide() method what about other differences.

Is anyone faster?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hide makes the form invisible to the user. Close actually closes it and calls dispose on it.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close(v=vs.110).aspx

"When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are closed and the form is disposed. "

Answer (score 8):

`form.Close()` unloads the form from memory and makes it available to be garbage collected; you can no longer interact with the form in code.

`form.Hide()` just hides the form, but you can still interact with it in your code.

---

So it is not really a question of which one is faster, but rather "are you really done using this form or not"?

Answer (score 1):

Hide only hides the form from the screen. Close is of course closes the form. If you want to get rid of the form that you don't want to use anymore then you should use Close. Hide and Close are different things.

Answer (score 1):

Ditto the above... Typically the way you open the form determines which to use. If you use .Show() the calling code continues while the form is loaded and shown. If you use ShowDialog() then calling code stops while the form is loaded and shown. When you Hide the called form the calling code resumes to the next statement.

Here is a sample of the second case:

```
        Dim frm As New frmSearch2
    frm.inFormName = "frmFacility"
    frm.ShowDialog(Me)
    If frm.outPrimaryKey.Length > 0 Then
        frmMain.Open_Form("frmFacility", frm.outPrimaryKey)
    End If
    frm.Close
    frm = Nothing
```

outPrimaryKey is a form level Public variable. You can also address any of the controls on the form.