# How do I get my Access form to re-open to the last unbound text box entries?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have created a form to update criteria in various queries in my database.  I have 4 unbound text boxes.  The user enters the new dates into the text boxes and I've added a button to run the queries.  The query results look great.

The problem is, I want to be able to close the form and upon re-open have the dates that were last entered re-appear. Instead, the text boxes are blank and the user has to re-enter the dates.

Basically, the same dates will be used for a month, then at month end, the dates will change. I would like to be able to set the default to the last entry.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using **unbound** textboxes, consider creating a table containing a single record to store the values entered in each textbox, and then use the table fields as the **Control Source** for each textbox.

This way, when the user enters/changes the value in the textbox, the underlying table record is automatically modified and will be automatically reloaded when the form is reopened.

You can also set the **Allow Additions** & **Allow Deletions** properties both to `No` in the Form Data properties, so that the user cannot create/delete the record in the underlying table being used to save the textbox values. Make sure that **Allow Edits** is set to `Yes` to ensure that the user can change the values in the textboxes, and that the **Recordset Type** is `Dynaset` so that it can be edited.

Using this method should also not require any changes to the rest of your existing application, since the values held by the bound textboxes may be read in the same way as if they were unbound.

Comment: Thank you, I took your advice and created a table to use as a Record Source for the form and Control Source for the text boxes.  The dates from the table are showing up when I open the form now!  However, I've run into another issue where I cannot edit the dates in the text boxes now.  I've searched through the Form property sheets for all of the selection types to make sure the appropriate properties are editable.  I can't seem to find the solution, any suggestions?

Comment: @Katz You're welcome! Have you ensured that `Allow Edits = Yes` and that `Recordset Type = Dynaset` in the Form Data properties so that the table values can be edited? (I've updated my answer above to include this information).

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Yes, the Allow Edits are all "Yes."  In fact, I also set the Allow Additions, Deletions, and Filters to "Yes," just to see if it would allow me to edit.  I've tried Dynaset and Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates).  Data Entry is "No" and Record Locks is "All Records."

Comment: @Katz Is `Locked = No` for the textbox itself?

Comment: Yes, Locked=No for all text boxes, Enabled =Yes, and Filter Lookup =Database Default.

Comment: @Katz When you say that you cannot edit the dates, are you able to change the values and unable to commit the change (i.e. take focus away from the textbox), or are you unable to even change the values?

Comment: Unable to even change the values

Comment: @Katz I'm running out of ideas on why that would be... I cannot replicate the behaviour you have described. I could only suggest that you post a new question to the site, with screenshots of the properties for one textbox whose value cannot be altered, and screenshots of the Form Data properties, and of the field properties for the data.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know exactly what you're asking without seeing the code you have, but if you are using VBA, you could look into the difference between hiding the form and closing/unloading the form as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20526250/difference-form-close-and-form-hide) If you hide the form, it won't be visible to the user, but it will still be loaded, so your text boxes should keep their values. When the user needs to interact with the form again, you can un-hide it.